# Setting Up Cross-Compilation In Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, yocto

I'd like to set up cross toolchain compilation for my embedded tartget with Yocto/Linux. Actually I am running Eclipse on my Windows 7 host and on my embedded target I have Yocto/Linux with gcc compiler installed.

I can't run Eclipse IDE on target itself but just I want to use target gcc compiler to compile nateivelyu for target.

Is it possible to setup Eclipse to get compiled Linux application on target?

Answer (score 0):

This is the Wiki for Eclipse set up: http://wiki.hioproject.org/index.php?title=HIO_Wiki:Set_Up_Eclipse_IDE_for_Yocto_Device

You will need to compile:

```
$bitbake meta-ide-support
$bitbake meta-toolchain adt-installer
```

Install the toolchain:

```
$sudo sh poky-eglibc-x86_64-meta-toolchain-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-toolchain-1.6.1.sh
```

Then go to Eclipse to install the Yocto Plugin, ADT plug-ins as well as well as connecting to the Cross Compile Tool Chain.